# Composer install return problems for missing extensions

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to deploy my project to a digitalocean ubuntu server. I've successfully cloned my project to the server, then I ran composer install to install the necessary packages.

Then this is the error that I'm getting:

```
Problem 1
    - laravel/framework is locked to version v8.73.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - laravel/framework v8.73.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mbstring extension.
  Problem 2
    - league/commonmark is locked to version 2.0.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - league/commonmark 2.0.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mbstring extension.
  Problem 3
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet is locked to version 1.19.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.19.0 requires ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
  Problem 4
    - phpoffice/phpword is locked to version 0.18.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpoffice/phpword 0.18.2 requires ext-xml * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's xml extension.
  Problem 5
    - simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode is locked to version 4.2.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode 4.2.0 requires ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
  Problem 6
    - spatie/image is locked to version 1.10.5 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - spatie/image 1.10.5 requires ext-mbstring * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mbstring extension.
  Problem 7
    - tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles is locked to version 2.2.3 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles 2.2.3 requires ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
  Problem 8
    - facade/ignition is locked to version 2.16.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - facade/ignition 2.16.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mbstring extension.
  Problem 9
    - phar-io/manifest is locked to version 2.0.3 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phar-io/manifest 2.0.3 requires ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
  Problem 10
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage is locked to version 9.2.9 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage 9.2.9 requires ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
  Problem 11
    - phpunit/phpunit is locked to version 9.5.10 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpunit/phpunit 9.5.10 requires ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
  Problem 12
    - theseer/tokenizer is locked to version 1.2.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - theseer/tokenizer 1.2.1 requires ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
  Problem 13
    - laravel/framework v8.73.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mbstring extension.
    - laravel/sail v1.12.5 requires illuminate/console ^8.0|^9.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.73.1].
    - laravel/sail is locked to version v1.12.5 and an update of this package was not requested.


To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-apcu.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

I did experience some of these error when I was developing my project on a windows machine, so I simply uncommented the required extensions on the /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini, I also checked all the files listed below the /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini and all them are enabled already. I tried to fix the Problem 1 first to see if it could be easily resolved by uncommenting the extension. I searched for a bit then, I did uncommented the extension_dir = "./" and extension=mbstring, then I ran composer install again, now I'm getting this error:

```
PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension 'opcache.so' (tried: ./opcache.so (./opcache.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./opcache.so.so (./opcache.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring' (tried: ./mbstring (./mbstring: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./mbstring.so (./mbstring.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqlnd.so' (tried: ./mysqlnd.so (./mysqlnd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./mysqlnd.so.so (./mysqlnd.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo.so' (tried: ./pdo.so (./pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./pdo.so.so (./pdo.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'apcu.so' (tried: ./apcu.so (./apcu.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./apcu.so.so (./apcu.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'calendar.so' (tried: ./calendar.so (./calendar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./calendar.so.so (./calendar.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ctype.so' (tried: ./ctype.so (./ctype.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./ctype.so.so (./ctype.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl.so' (tried: ./curl.so (./curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./curl.so.so (./curl.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'exif.so' (tried: ./exif.so (./exif.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./exif.so.so (./exif.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ffi.so' (tried: ./ffi.so (./ffi.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./ffi.so.so (./ffi.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'fileinfo.so' (tried: ./fileinfo.so (./fileinfo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./fileinfo.so.so (./fileinfo.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ftp.so' (tried: ./ftp.so (./ftp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./ftp.so.so (./ftp.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gettext.so' (tried: ./gettext.so (./gettext.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./gettext.so.so (./gettext.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'iconv.so' (tried: ./iconv.so (./iconv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./iconv.so.so (./iconv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli.so' (tried: ./mysqli.so (./mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./mysqli.so.so (./mysqli.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql.so' (tried: ./pdo_mysql.so (./pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./pdo_mysql.so.so (./pdo_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'phar.so' (tried: ./phar.so (./phar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./phar.so.so (./phar.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'posix.so' (tried: ./posix.so (./posix.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./posix.so.so (./posix.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'readline.so' (tried: ./readline.so (./readline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./readline.so.so (./readline.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'shmop.so' (tried: ./shmop.so (./shmop.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./shmop.so.so (./shmop.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sockets.so' (tried: ./sockets.so (./sockets.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./sockets.so.so (./sockets.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sysvmsg.so' (tried: ./sysvmsg.so (./sysvmsg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./sysvmsg.so.so (./sysvmsg.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sysvsem.so' (tried: ./sysvsem.so (./sysvsem.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./sysvsem.so.so (./sysvsem.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sysvshm.so' (tried: ./sysvshm.so (./sysvshm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./sysvshm.so.so (./sysvshm.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'tokenizer.so' (tried: ./tokenizer.so (./tokenizer.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./tokenizer.so.so (./tokenizer.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP's phar extension is missing. Composer requires it to run. Enable the extension or recompile php without --disable-phar then try again.
```

Comment: comment the extension_dir again and try installing the extensions with your package manage. If you are using a debian based system you can use `sudo apt install php8.0-{mbstring,dom,gd}`

Comment: @A.Rahimi thanks it worked! I did not need to change anything on the php.ini file just need to install the needed extensions.